# How to reconnect to paired devices iOS BLE

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I am trying to retrieve bonded devices when I press pair on the Pairing request:

[image]

Once I go out of range it will disconnect, but once I come back into range how do I make it auto connect to the app? I know it is auto-connecting to the OS because if I see on the native settings it shows connected.